# How can I weight down specific terms in CountVectorizer plus cosine_similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cosine-similarity

I'm writing some code where I take a bunch of documents that have subject codes attached to them, and then run a CountVectorizer over them, to generate similarities with a user profile.

So if we're calling the subject codes A, B, C, etc., then I have documents like this loaded into a dataframe:

```
| Document ID | Subject Codes |
|-------------|---------------|
| 1           | A B           |
| 2           | B C           |
| 3           | C             |
```

etc.

So the first thing I do is run CountVectorizer fit_transform on the subject codes field and store that into `subject_code_count_matrix`

Users have ratings (out of 5) for various (but not all) documents, and so to get recommendations for a user, I load all of their ratings and the associated document IDs. The ratings are out of 5 so I divide them by 5 to weight them. This results in a dataframe like this:

```
| Document ID | Weighted Rating |
|-------------|-----------------|
| 2           | 0.4             |
```

etc.

So then I generate a user profile like this:

```py
user_profile = np.dot(subject_code_count_matrix[user_ratings['index'].values].toarray().T, user_ratings['weighted_rating'].values)
```

Then in order to generate documents the user might be interested in, I do this:

```py
user_subject_code_similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(np.atleast_2d(user_profile), subject_code_count_matrix))
for index, score in user_subject_code_similarity_matrix.iloc[0].sort_values(ascending=False).iteritems():
    ... sorted values are here
```

So my question - is there a way for me to weight down any document containing a specific subject code? Like right now users rate documents, and my understanding is that rating a document with a low score only weights down documents that look similar to that one. So in my example above, if I wanted to generally weight down any document containing subject code C, even rating document 3 with a minimum score of 1 (weighted rating of 0.2), only rates down documents that look like document 3 which is documents that have exactly the subject code C, not any document with subject code C - is that correct? So is there a way for me to rate down documents with a specific subject code in addition to the user's profile?

Ideally I don't want to mess with the `subject_code_count_matrix` variable because this is generated over a very large set of documents (it takes multiple minutes to generate), and I reuse it multiple times for the comparisons. I would be fine with copying it though if weighting can be achieved that way.

Comment: Did you think about `TfidfVectorizer` instead of `CountVectorizer` ?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I did think about it but what benefit would that provide here? I am not too concerned with ranking up terms which appear infrequently, I want all terms to have the same weight (except when I don't, which is the exception and the basis of my question). Unless TF-IDF provides me a way to weight terms in this manner?